# Python 2.7 Matrix Multiplication Equivalent to the Dot Product?

Tags: pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array, rounding-error

I have 2 issues nested as one:

```
n_rows, n_cols = np.shape(Z)
ZT = Z.transpose()
ZTZ = np.dot(ZT,Z) # does return a value
ZTZ1 = np.matmul(ZT,Z) # error
print("Close?")
print(np.allclose(ZTZ,ZTZ1))
print("----")


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-211-f26bdaebc910> in <module>()
 26 
 27 print
---> 28 coV = getCovariance(df)
 29 #print(coV)
 30 print

<ipython-input-211-f26bdaebc910> in getCovariance(df)
 13     ZT = Z.transpose()
 14     ZTZ = np.dot(ZT,Z)
---> 15     ZTZ1 = np.matmul(ZT,Z)
 16     print("Close?")
 17     print(np.allclose(ZTZ,ZTZ1))

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matmul'
```

Okay ... so obviously matmul doesn't exist on my machine. Got it. Now how do I confirm that the dot is doing the same thing? Because I have a matrix that was once a `pandas.DataFrame` object and I converted it to a matrix through it's `.as_matrix()` method and I am getting rounding errors and need to check where things went wrong ... I also tried the standard `*` operator, but that doesn't work either on np.ndarray matrix objects.

SIDE NOTE: if there are *any* pro tips on rounding that could be transferred from someone with experience with pandas, that is also much appreciated because I can't seem to find out how pandas has given me a different matrix than a build in function from the numpy class (I have been asked to reimplement the function).

Comment: What is the shape of `Z`?  For 2d arrays, `matmul` is the same as `dot`.

Comment: ~20,000 x 10, so yes it would be a 2d array. Ok thx.